# How can I put a break between two elements contained by a span using css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:2689/" method="post">
    <span>
        <label for="SearchBag.PowerSearchKeys" id="Label1"> Key words</label>
        <input id="SearchBag.PowerSearchKeys" name="SearchBag.PowerSearchKeys" type="text" value="" />             
        <button id="powerSearchSubmitButton"  class="fancySubmitButton" type="submit"><span><em>Search</em></span></button>
        <a href="Search.mvc/EmptyAdvancedSearch" id="advancedSearchLinkButton"  class="fancyLinkButton"><span><em>Advanced</em></span></a>
    </span>        
</form>
```

The form's content needs to be centered over it's width (100% in this case).
The anchor needs to be directly under the button.

Because a picture can say a thousand words, here's the result of my awesome paint art skills:

[image]
<sub>(source: [telenet.be](http://users.telenet.be/boersnoes/layOut.jpg))</sub>

And this whole block should be centered on the webpage.

**--EDIT--**
Because the content of all the controlls can varry greatly in length, I cannot give any element any width specifications (not even in %). Also, over estimating the width would leave confusing white spaces between elements. This too is not a desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting 'display: block' on each element that you want on a separate line.  You may also need to play with the margin and padding to get them centered (like margin-left: 50%; padding-left: -[1/2 width of element]) and text-align: center.

Comment: Can't use element widths because almost everything will get translated and can have all kinds of widths

Answer (score 2):

Why not just put a break in before the  tag (
) then align the  to the right?

Comment: you should be able to right align it in your span if the other elements take the full width of the span.

Comment: There is no parent tag with fitting width. It has the full width of the screen and text-align: center;

Comment: Your span should have a width, and should have its left/right margins set as auto to center it.  This will solve your problem.

Comment: @ck: spans are inline elements

Comment: @borisCallens: then you should really be using a `div` instead of a `span`.  Are you still trying to figure this one out two years later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I usually float form elements (left), and if I want to put the next one on a new line i use clear:left.

Comment: But if I want to center my form elements float f***s it up

Comment: Put a div around things you want to center and use margin:0 auto; on it and specify a width. You could also do this on the form itself if you want to center the whole form. The floats are relative to its container being the div or form. So floating form elements doesn't 'f*** up' anything...

Comment: centering floats always means fixed size. Because off translation I can never know how long elements will be.

Comment: @boris callens: you don't have to used fixed size to center floats. You can use %

Comment: Yes, but that's still a width. I don't know how much I'm going to need. And putting too much width gives confusing whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace the `<span>` with a `<fieldset>` for semantic correctness (I don't think span brings a lot to the table in terms of functionality), and apply some styling to that `fieldset` to the tune of

```
fieldset {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

I can't tell for sure if that'll line up the anchor and the button correctly or not, but since the `fieldset` has `position: relative` set, you'll be able to position stuff if you need to with relative ease.

Comment: What would be the advantage of the fieldset over the span except for needing another css rule to disable the border?

Answer (score 0):

As much as i hate to say it, this is a case where use of tables might be considered.
But I would try positioning - i made a quick & dirty solution here
[at JSbin](http://jsbin.com/izewu4/2)

Basically you put your form into an element, center it with `text-align` and make the container `position: relative`. Then you use the id in the link to position it absolutely in reference to the parent. But it only works if the parent is an inline element.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you change its display property (and you shouldn't), the `span` element should be an inline element, meaning that it exists in the flow of text. Putting block level elements inside an inline element isn't really a good idea.

You also have a lot of extraneous tags in there. Instead of this:

```
<button id="powerSearchSubmitButton" class="fancySubmitButton" type="submit">
    <span><em>Search</em></span>
</button>
```

why not just do this:

```
<button id="powerSearchSubmitButton" class="fancySubmitButton" type="submit">
    Search
</button>
```

The `span` does nothing, and the `em` can be emulated through CSS:

```
.fancySubmitButton { font-style: italic }`
```

Here's what I'd do:

```
<form>
    <label for="SearchBag.PowerSearchKeys" id="Label1">Key words</label>
    <input id="SearchBag.PowerSearchKeys" name="SearchBag.PowerSearchKeys" type="text" value="" />             
    <button id="powerSearchSubmitButton"  class="fancySubmitButton" type="submit">Search</button>
    <a href="Search.mvc/EmptyAdvancedSearch" id="advancedSearchLinkButton"  class="fancyLinkButton">Advanced</a>
</form>
```

with the CSS:

```
form {
    text-align: center;
}
.fancySubmitButton, .fancyLinkButton {
    font-style: italic;
}
.fancyLinkButton {
    display: block;  /* this will put it on its own line */
}
```

Quick response to the comments: giving something the class "fancyLinkButton" *doesn't* imply that it has rounded corners. Anyway, if you want to put rounded corners on certain elements, I would still avoid using extraneous markup. If more wrapper elements are needed for whatever implementation you're using, then those should be added via Javascript. Remember that mozilla and webkit already support CSS rounded corners - eventually IE will too, and you'll be able to easily change your single javascript function, rather than wading through HTML to find everywhere where there are unneeded spans.

Comment: HTML's rules for block/inline/flow content have *nothing* to do with CSS concept of block and inline. It's perfectly valid to put display:block on span.

Comment: The extra tags is (as the class hints) for making rounded buttons.

Comment: Also, I don't want to put each on its own line because that wouldn't make sence in the rest of the lay-out.
I need them to be as described in OP

Comment: @boris callens: what do you mean with not wanting to put each on it's own line?

Comment: I need the first three elements to be on a line and the last element to be on a line, right under the button. I'll update the OP to clear things up.

Comment: @porneL, I didn't say that you *can't* put display: block on a span, I just said you *shouldn't*. It's like redefining the basic building blocks of a language. It can still work, but it makes your readability and maintainability suffer.

Comment: @nickf: don't take this offensive, I was (and am) merely trying to justify why those elements are there.
As I don't like to rely on JS, I made an HTML helper method in my personal asp.net-mvc helper lib. If ever all browsers support rounded css, I will change the code there.